# Scrapy Crawls only 1st page and not the rest

Tags: python, django, scrapy

heya I am making a Project using scrapy in which I need to scrap the business details from a business directory http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair
the problem I am facing is: when I am trying to crawl the page my crawler fetches the details of only 1st page whereas I need to fetch the details of the rest 9 pages also; that is all 10 pages..
i am showing below my Spider code and items.py and settings .py 
please see my code and help me to solve it

spider code::

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from project2.items import Project2Item

class ProjectSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project2spider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://directory.thesun.co.uk/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="abTbl "]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = Project2Item()
            item['Catogory'] = site.select('span[@class="icListBusType"]/text()').extract()
            item['Bussiness_name'] = site.select('a/@title').extract()
            item['Description'] = site.select('span[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['Number'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/@id').extract()
            item['Web_url'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['adress_name'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['Photo_name'] = site.select('img/@alt').extract()
            item['Photo_path'] = site.select('img/@src').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

My items.py code is as follows::

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Project2Item(Item):
    Catogory = Field()
    Bussiness_name = Field()
    Description = Field()
    Number = Field()
    Web_url = Field()
    adress_name = Field()
    Photo_name = Field()
    Photo_path = Field()
```

my settings.py is:::

```
BOT_NAME = 'project2'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['project2.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'project2.spiders'
```

please help
me to extract details from other pages too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working code. Scrolling the pages should be taken by studying the
website and its scroll structure and apply them acccordingly. In this case, the website has given it "/page/x" where x is the page number.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from project2spider.items import Project2Item
from scrapy.http import Request

class ProjectSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project2spider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://directory.thesun.co.uk"]
    current_page_no = 1 
    start_urls = [ 
        "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair"
    ]   

    def get_next_url(self, fired_url):
        if '/page/' in fired_url:
            url, page_no = fired_url.rsplit('/page/', 1)
        else:
            if self.current_page_no != 1:
                #end of scroll
                return 
        self.current_page_no += 1
        return "http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/%s" % self.current_page_no

    def parse(self, response):
        fired_url = response.url
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="abTbl "]')
        for site in sites:
            item = Project2Item()
            item['Catogory'] = site.select('span[@class="icListBusType"]/text()').extract()
            item['Bussiness_name'] = site.select('a/@title').extract()
            item['Description'] = site.select('span[last()]/text()').extract()
            item['Number'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/@id').extract()
            item['Web_url'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['adress_name'] = site.select('span[@class="searchInfoLabel"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['Photo_name'] = site.select('img/@alt').extract()
            item['Photo_path'] = site.select('img/@src').extract()
            yield item
        next_url = self.get_next_url(fired_url)
        if next_url:
            yield Request(next_url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check the paging links they look like this:

http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/3
http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/2

You could loop pages using urllib2 with a variable

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://directory.thesun.co.uk/find/uk/computer-repair/page/' + page)
html = response.read()
```

and scrape the html.

Answer (score 0):

I try the code that @nizam.sp. posted and this only displays 2 records  1 record(last record) from the main page and 1 record from the second page(random record) and it ends.